# How to add dollar signs in Code Snippets of Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

### **$ (dollar signs)** are removed from Snippets in Visual Studio Code

#### How to disable placeholders?

My vue-html.json file snippet

```json
"body": ["<ActivityIndicator  v-if=\"$apollo.loading\" />"]
```

does not add `$` and produces

```
<ActivityIndicator v-if="apollo.loading"  />
```

but instead it should produce

```
<ActivityIndicator v-if="$apollo.loading" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  "description": {
    "prefix": "trigger",
    "body": [
      "<ActivityIndicator v-if=\"\\$apollo.loading\" />"
    ],
    "description": "description"
  }
```

In JSON the backslash itself needs to be encoded with `\`, which is why you need `\\`

Answer (score 0):

`"body": ["<ActivityIndicator  v-if=\"\\$apollo.loading\" />"]`

You need to escape the `$` symbol individually too